# What is the meaning of the expression "I prefer the enchilada"?

Tags: expressions

Context:
I met a well-traveled and -educated man. Upon him leaving I asked, "Chris, right?" He responded, laughing, "Christopher. I prefer the enchilada."

Comment: I've always heard the expression, "the WHOLE enchilada", meaning, in context, of course, everything that is available or being offered.  That's the first time I heard it in reference to a name before.

Comment: It looks like he is saying the same thing as @KristinaLopez suggested, but just shortened the sentence.

Comment: "I prefer the enchilada" is vastly different from "I prefer the whole enchilada," as the second expression's keyword is "whole." Yet I cannot help but see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 4):

When the gentleman replied, he just shortened the sentence, from saying:

> "Christopher. I prefer the **whole** enchilada."

Using the expression that Kristina stated in her comment, as '[the whole enchilada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchilada#Etymology)' refers to the 'whole thing' - in this case, the gentleman's full name.

Comment: Yup. This is like saying "I haven't the faintest." Everyone knows you mean "I haven't the faintest *idea*" (or *inkling*, or *clue*, or whatever other word people in your circle tend to use).